# puppetlabs_spec_helper/rake_tasks - validate task - skip validation of specific file

Tags: rake, puppet, rake-task, rspec-puppet

I have a Puppet module which I'm setting up overall tests. I'm using `puppetlabs_spec_helper/rake_tasks` to get a sane task list, and defined a default task in my Rakefile:

```
require 'puppetlabs_spec_helper/rake_tasks'

task :default => [:validate, :lint, :spec]
```

But my `metadata.json` file will always fail, because the Puppet modules developed internally in my company don't follow standard naming - not for the modules themselves, nor for their tags.

How do I instruct Rake to skip just `metadata.json` file validation?

Meanwhile, I'm using as a workaround `:syntax` task in place of `:validate`.

Comment: If you convert to PDK I believe it has a `.pdkignore` file.

Comment: I don't think `.pdkignore` has the wanted effect, but I haven't used it. What little documentation there is says `.pdkignore` is about what files get packaged into a module package.

Comment: However, [PDK does provide a way to specify files to ignore during validation](https://www.puppet.com/docs/pdk/3.x/pdk_testing#ignoring-files-during-module-validation).

Comment: On the other hand, PDK also relies on some of the contents of `metadata.json` for operational purposes, so it might not be a good fit.